# Sent 95BTC to my client from Mt.Gox and it never showed

Tags: transactions, client, mac

I have had Bitcoin for some time now, but am relatively inexperienced. I have a Mac client, and yesterday sent 95BTC to it from my Mt.Gox wallet but it never arrived. I sent Mt.Gox a message asking for help they told me it would arrive when I reached block 160319 and my client is just at 124667 and not connecting at all! I can't get it to connect, have tried various suggestions from forums but can't make it work, please help! thanks

Comment: First, calm down - your money is safe. Not sure why you're client is not connecting - I believe there is a question on this site that already explains this. The BTC will only show up on your account when you reach the correct block count.

Comment: Other question with connection problems on a Mac: [Bitcoin client won't connect to the network](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/bitcoin-client-wont-connect-to-the-network). I'd say this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: Can I ask to the @user858 user858 to please tell us the end of history, this helps to spread a word (good or bad).

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are not sure if your wallet balance is okay, search for your address in the [Block Explorer](http://blockexplorer.com/). If you see your coins there, they are safe. [I'm guessing it's this address, so everything should be fine.](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1FHfgKEcEu4HTkQeULzKXMnvdjxZVpP5Tj)
2. Make sure your client is up-to-date. If it is too old it might not be able to communicate with the network. (remember to [backup your wallet.dat beforehand](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet#Locating_Bitcoin.27s_data_directory))
3. If your updated client can't connect to the network (0 connections), [check out this topic](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/bitcoin-client-wont-connect-to-the-network).
4. If your client is connected to peers, but after an hour you don't see any block progress, try closing down the client, deleting blk .dat files from your [Bitcoin data directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet#Locating_Bitcoin.27s_data_directory), and then starting it again.
5. When you see your block count progressing, be patient. Leave your computer running the client over night. The procedure takes awhile, as Bitcoin needs to download and verify over 1GB of data.

If all else fails, you can try redeeming your wallet at MtGox (remember exactly if this is the only service providing this functionality) and using an [online wallet service](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Browser-based_wallet), like [StrongCoin](https://strongcoin.com/), to never have to deal with the problem again.