# Bitcoin QT wallet doesn't sync

Tags: wallet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bitcoin client won’t connect to the network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/bitcoin-client-wont-connect-to-the-network)

I'm using an iMac with OSX 10.8. Bitcoin-Qt which never seems to sync. I have withdrawn coins from Mt.Gox to an address generated by Bitcoin-Qt. While the transaction has registered with Mt.Gox, there is nothing in my wallet. Do I just leave it open until it syncs, start agin or what?

Comment: What is your number of connections and blocks? If there is any progress in the number of blocks you should just wait it out (0.8 will be much faster). If you have no connections try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the transaction fee? If you don't, most miners won't accept it. The same thing happened to me.

Also, you need to wait until it syncs. You can check if it's been included by going to `blockchain.info/address/*the address to which you sent it*`. If it worked, the transaction should be listed there.

Comment: It was sent *from* Mt.Gox, so it's very unlikely that a transaction fee was omitted. I don't believe that the site allows the user to choose their fee.

Comment: Yes it does. When I decided not to, it simply didn't show up anywhere else but Mt.Gox said that I had withdrawed it.