# Install a pre-synchronized blockchain

Tags: blockchain, installation, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I download the whole block chain from somewhere?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/799/can-i-download-the-whole-block-chain-from-somewhere)

My Bitcoin client has been "synchronizing" for a really ridiculously long time making the computer leggy. According to [this article](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/FAQ#How_long_does_.22synchronizing.22_take_when_the_Bitcoin_client_is_first_installed.3F_What.27s_it_doing.3F) I can download a pre-synchronized block chain from [here](http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/). What do I do after I download bootstrap.dat?

Seriously it says "Version 0.7.1 (when released) will automatically validate and import a file in the data directory" but where the hell's the data directory?