# Best way to update an outdated blockchain

Tags: blockchain

I have a relatively slow computer and a slow internet connection. For this reason, I only open the bitcoin client when I really have to (because it uses a whole lot of bandwidth and CPU to download and verify the blockchain). However, as a consequence each time I open the client I now have even more to download and verify. At this point, I haven't opened the client for about 8 months. What is the best way to update the blockchain on my computer? I care much more about speed than about verification of the block chain.

I have initiated the torrent file (bootstrap.dat), but it will take about a week to download and [in this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/799/can-i-download-the-whole-block-chain-from-somewhere) I read that it is not supported nor updated anymore. Before I continue this very lengthy download, I wanted to see if this is actually the right method for my situation.

Using linux and the bitcoin-qt client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to simply update your client to the latest version (0.10.1 was just published) and just run it. As of 0.10 it will download the missing months much faster. (As well as many wallet improvements.)

Forget about the bootstrap file, just cancel the download. It's three months old, so you would still end up with the same problem.

Also: you're probably better off regularly running the bitcoin client (maybe a scheduled task, once a week?) instead of letting it get behind 8 months. You might want to add the -listen=0 option, that way you won't have others connect to you and download blocks from you (saving you some bandwidth).

If it's really too heavy for you, you might consider a different wallet as Pieter mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap.dat file will still work, and if you already have part of it, it's probably better to continue.

It's not longer updated because the synchronization code in Bitcoin Core 0.10 and afterwards works similar to how Bittorrent works (also from several peers at once, etc.), but verifies the data as it comes in, rather than only after you are done.

But if you're only using the client every few months, I presume you just want it for the wallet. There are other wallet clients available, which do not require downloading and processing the entire chain.

Comment: If he's "only" 8 months behind, I don't think there's much point in continuing the bootstrap file? That would still be months behind and mostly download what he already has.