# What happened to the bootstrap.dat provided by bitcoin.org?

Tags: bootstrap.dat, bitcoin.org

I could download a `bootstrap.dat.torrent` from  [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/bin/blockchain/bootstrap.dat.torrent) before, but it is no longer available. Does bitcoin.org still maintain it?

Is there another source for downloading a `bootstrap.dat`? I am stuck with a 0.9.x version of BitcoinCore for testing purposes, and the `bootstrap.dat` would improve synchronization for me.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Can I download the whole block chain from somewhere?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/799/5406)

Comment: I know bootstrap.dat, it just because bitcoin.org remove the link of bootstrap.dat.torrent.

Comment: Sorry, if I changed the intent of your question. Please feel free to rollback my changes or further edit your post to better align it with your intent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As user [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/24925/bitcoin) has already pointed out, using a bootstrap.dat is no longer recommended—you can see the release notes for the new [faster-synchronization feature here](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.10.0#faster-synchronization).

As a result, the bootstrap.dat torrent links were removed from bitcoin.org after a [short discussion](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/issues/846).

The bootstrap.dat file is still [available here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145386.0) on the bitcointalk.org forum, and jgarzik has indicated that he will continue to occasionally [update it](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145386.msg11235170#msg11235170) "for academic research and development purposes."

Another alternative is the version which has been maintained by [Armory](https://bitcoinarmory.com/about-bitcoin-security/) Technologies, [available here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/bitcoinarmory-media/bootstrap.dat.torrent). At the time of this writing, it is more up-to-date than jgarzik's bootstrap.dat, however it's not clear if it will receive any future updates.

Comment: To whomever downvoted my answer: can you please explain why this is incorrect and/or how it can be improved?

Comment: I think yours is an exemplary answer. It treats all aspects of the question, i.e. why the `bootstrap.dat` its no longer listed on bitcoin.org, where the bootstrap still can be found andwhat alternative approaches exist. Meanwhile, it is well-written and commendably sourced. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Murch Much obliged; regardless I'm always open to constructive criticism and to fixing any mistakes I make.

Comment: Your answer is what I want to know, thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherGurnee: Would it be possible to download the Blockchain with BitcoinCore 0.10.x and use it with 0.9.x?

Comment: @Murch Afraid not—headers-first broke backwards compatibility of the block files and LevelDB databases (noted [here in the release notes](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.10.0#downgrading-warning)).

Comment: @ChristopherGurnee: What I meant was, I see the downvote, but I don't see an (obvious) reason for it.

Comment: @Murch Me neither ;)  I was just leaving open some benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary so is not being updated anymore. Using a bootstrap torrent is slower than downloading from the network using Bitcoin Core 0.10.0 or above due to improvements in the block downloading method.

Comment: Thank you, but I need use 0.9.x for now, because my program is not test for 0.10.x yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thread where someone is providing updated `bootstrap.dat` downloads on BitcoinTalk:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1310261.msg13412290#msg13412290

Answer (score 0):

I see it here:
https://bitcoin.org/bin/block-chain/

Maybe it was removed but it's back again?